# Java creational design patterns for FooProvider/FooManager and Foo object

Tags: java, design-patterns

Recently, I worked on a user-friendly library which will provide users with a Resource object. This Resource object will be instantiated by my ResourceProvider/ ResourceManager/ResourceFactory, and ResourceProvider/ ResourceManager/ResourceFactory might have different implementations based on different context;

Besides, ResouceProvider/ResourceManager/ResourceFactory will have a cache across an application for Resource object based on the resource name.

```
ResourceManager mgr = ResourceManager.getInstance(context);
Resource r = mgr.getResource('myName')
```

My first thought is using a static factory method. My question is that what is the best pattern for this case. I think builder pattern is kind overkill since there is only one context parameter. Any idea is welcome!!

Comment: Why do you need any pattern here? Provide common interface and dependency inversion to provide proper implementation. Cache is internal stuff, specific for specific implementation and is completely irrelevant in this case

Answer (score 1):

So your question is about API-Design?

Your API design is common, but not without disadvantages to consider. With your approach every instance of *ResourceManager* must also extends the *ResourceManager* class, what have some drawbacks:

- Thight coupling of all implementation with *ResourceManager*.
- Hard if a *ResourceManager* also extends some other class, not under your control.
- Violation of [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), because implemenations doesn't need the *getInstance* method, but do offer it via *ResourceManager*.

From a architectual viewpoint, a design with *ResourceManager* as interface and extra provider for getting implementations, would be nicer:

```
ResourceManager mgr = ResourceManagerProvider.getInstance(context);
```

But than, one problem is left:

- [Static methods must not, but CAN be bad](https://dzone.com/articles/why-static-bad-and-how-avoid). It's hard to mock the *ResourceManagerProvider* (e.g. for testcases) because of the static "*getInstance*" method.

The cleanest way would be to use no external static methods:

```
ResourceManager mgr = new ResourceManagerProvider().getInstance(context);
```

(internal, ResourceManagerProvider could use private static methods to get same result.)

But from an user viewpoint, i think your approach is more popular, because easy to use. So no pattern or "golden bullet", just a decision.

A alternative migth be to rely on [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), but this depends hard on your requirements. Using depency injection first requires the user of your library to use of the same depency injection framework as you, and makes must sense if you can inject the needed context. With dependency injection a user wouldn't request the ResourceManager direct, but let inject it from the framework.